# How to print all defined variables except for the ones that are equal to 0 - Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Note:** I am using `Python 3`

I am trying to figure out how to print all other numbers that are set in the variables (in this case `num1`, `num2`, `num3` and `num4`) except for zeros. I have been playing around with my code for the last 2 to 3 days and have not found any solution yet. I searched on the internet for any tutorials / code examples but still to no avail.

```py
num1 = 0
num2 = 2
num3 = 3
num4 = 4

if num1 != 0:
    test1 = num1
elif num2 != 0:
    test2 = num2
elif num3 != 0:
    test3 = num3
elif num4 != 0:
    test4 = num4

print(test1, test2, test3, test4)
```

Here is the error that I keep on getting when I run the code above:

```
NameError: name 'test1' is not defined
```

I am sure that this is a pretty simple problem and that I am just missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to place all of the variables in a list is so...

```
numbers = [num1, num2, num3, num4]
```

Then use a loop to print to ones not equal to zero:

```
for num in numbers:
    if (num != 0):
        print(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, the statement `test1 = num1` would only get executed if the statement `if num1 != 0:` is true, which in your case is not. So, the test1 variable is not even getting created.

So, if you can create empty containers for test1, test2, test3 and test4; that would solve the purpose.

The code would look something like this:

```
num1 = 0
num2 = 2
num3 = 3
num4 = 4

test1 = test2 = test3 = test4 = 0

if num1 != 0:
    test1 = num1
elif num2 != 0:
    test2 = num2
elif num3 != 0:
    test3 = num3
elif num4 != 0:
    test4 = num4

print(test1, test2, test3, test4)
```

Output:  `(0, 2, 0, 0)`

Comment: I confused on why it prints out `0,2,0,0` can you explain?

Comment: @Alex `num1 != 0` is false, so it prints out the original value of test1 defined above, which is 0.  `num2 != 0` is true, so it prints out the value of num2.  So, the statement is satisfied, it doesn't care about the next two conditions, as you used `elif`.  So, if you used `if` instead of `elif` in the statements, your output would be `(0, 2, 3, 4)`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :-)

Answer (score 1):

That's because the variables test...n have no assigned values at the time of usage
Try this:

```
num1 = 0
num2 = 2
num3 = 3
num4 = 4

test1=test2=test3= test4= int()

if num1 != 0:
test1 = num1
elif num2 != 0:
test2 = num2
elif num3 != 0:
test3 = num3
elif num4 != 0:
test4 = num4

print(test1, test2, test3, test4)
```

Prints out : (0,2,0,0)

Comment: I confused on why it prints out `0,2,0,0` can you explain?